# How can I use a loop in R to create new, labeled variables and write them into a .csv?

Tags: r, loops, csv, variables

I have a table with eighty columns and I want to create columns by multiplying var1*var41 var1*var42....var1*var80. var2*var41 var2*var42...var2*var80. How could I write a loop to multiply the columns and write the labeled product into a .csv? The result should have 1600 additional columns.

Comment: R is made for especially such stuff and it can do this without   a loop. But you will need to get a basic hang of `apply` functions  in  R.  Here is a clue how to go about this problem : `apply(x, 2, function(a)(a*x[,1]))` . You will also need to come up with a scheme for naming these columns . The next step would be to use `cbind` to get everything into a singe dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at this with some fake data:

```
# Fake data (arbitraty 5 rows)
mtx <- sample(1:100, 5 * 80, replace = T)
dim(mtx) <- c(5,80)
colnames(mtx) <- paste0("V", 1:ncol(mtx)) # Name the original columns
mtx[1:5,1:5]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#[1,]  8 10 69 84 92
#[2,] 59 34 36 96 86
#[3,] 51 26 78 63  8
#[4,] 74 93 73 70 49
#[5,] 62 30 20 43  9
```

Using a for loop, one might try something like this:

```
v <- expand.grid(1:40,41:80) # all combos
v[c(1:3,1598:1600),]
#     Var1 Var2
#1       1   41
#2       2   41
#3       3   41
#1598   38   80
#1599   39   80
#1600   40   80

# Initialize matrix for multiplication results
newcols <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(mtx), ncol = nrow(v))
# Run the for loop
for(i in 1:nrow(v)) newcols[,i] <- mtx[,v[i,1]] * mtx[,v[i,2]]

# save the names as "V1xV41" format with apply over rows (Margin = 1)
# meaning, for each row in v, paste "V" in front and "x" between
colnames(newcols) <- apply(v, MARGIN = 1, function(eachv) paste0("V", eachv, collapse="x"))

# combine the additional 1600 columns
tocsv <- cbind(mtx, newcols)
tocsv[,78:83] # just to view old and new columns
#     V78 V79 V80 V1xV41 V2xV41 V3xV41
#[1,]  17  92  13    429    741   1079
#[2,]  70  94   1   4836   4464   5115
#[3,]   6  77  93   3740   1020   3468
#[4,]  88  34  26    486    258     66
#[5,]  48  77  61    873   4365    970

# Write it
write.csv(tocsv, "C:/Users/Evan Friedland/Documents/NEWFILENAME.csv")
```